# Javascript and a href with variables

Tags: javascript, html, variables, href

I have a little doubt about javascript, a new language that I'm studying...

I have a variables that contains a link, like

```
var Link = "http://www.example.com/search?q=javascriptvariable&k=&e=1";
```

I'd like to press a button and go to the link, that I've saved in a the variable Link. I've tryed with:

```
<a href=Link><input type="submit" value="Go" /></a>
```

What's wrong?

PS

The link I want to edit is not the link of my page (I can't use this.document.location.href). My button should redirect the user to another website and do a custom search.

**PPS**
If you want an example. I have a textbox on my website. If the user write something in my textbox and clicks the Go button the text in my textbox will replace JAVASCRIPTVARIABLE in 
http://search.aol.com/aol/search?enabled_terms=&s_it=comsearch51&q=JAVASCRIPTVARIABLE and will open the AOL research page.

Comment: How are you outputting that HTML?

Comment: You cannot use JavaScript variables as values for HTML attributes like this. Why do you think you can? You should read more introductory material. Also, having a button inside a link is very odd.

Comment: @FelixKling keep in mind the OP said they are learning. Be helpful rather than judgmental.

Comment: @user1453638 your edit / intended purpose sounds a little suspect?

Comment: Why can't you use document.location.href? It allows you to do everything a link can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your link

```
<input type="button" value="Go" onclick="document.location= Link;" />
```

Comment: Really? I would suggest to remove the link completely, or the button, one of them.

Comment: buttons are ugly and hard to style - you could always add the link programatically but personally I prefer to do it this way so that I can see what my layout will look like

Answer (score 2):

Give the link an ID first,

```
<a id="someLink"><input type="submit" value="Go" /></a>
```

Then, in your javascript you will need

```
var Link = "http://www.example.com/search?q=javascriptvariable&k=&e=1";
document.getElementById('someLink').href = Link;
```

Comment: I think that's the best approach as the html code stays pure html and the coding is done separately.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set it with JavaScript. It is also better to use a button.

HTML:

```
<button id="go">Go!</button>
```

​
JavaScript:

```
var Link = 'http://jsfiddle.net'

document.getElementById('go').onclick = function () {
    document.location= Link;
};​
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/PfWdW/

Comment: That is true, but I don't think it's a very helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" value="Go" onclick="location.href=Link;" />
```

Just noting I wouldn't recommend this type of approach.. but to answer it directly the above works. Why not just use a normal link without script?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
<input type="button" value="Go" onclick="window.location.href='http://www.example.com/search?q=javascriptvariable&k=&e=1'" />
```